# Tcl/tk: should I use for or foreach?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, tcl

I have three lists that I'd like to iterate through so that I evaluate each permutation of variables in my lists.  I currently have a `for` loop with two nested `for` loops, but I'm wondering if I can achieve the same with a `foreach`?  I can't quite figure out the `foreach` syntax, however. (Probably because I don't have a firm grasp of how/when to use `foreach`).

Here's my current block of code.  Is it possible to write this as a `foreach`?

```
set list1 {a b c}
set list2 {red blue green}
set list3 {dogs cats chickens}

for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list1]} {incr i} {
   for {set j 0} {$j < [llength $list2]} {incr j} {
      for {set k 0} {$k < [llength $list3]} {incr k} {
         set alpha [lindex $list1 $i]
         set color [lindex $list2 $j]
         set animal [lindex $list3 $k]
         puts "$alpha $color $animal"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `foreach` instead of `for` when you are iterating through a list and you don't need the indices, but rather the elements of the list themselves. For example, you could use the following instead of your current loops:

```
foreach alpha $list1 {
   foreach color $list2 {
      foreach animal $list3 {
         puts "$alpha $color $animal"
      }
   }
}
```

Please do take a look at the [manual on foreach](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm).

Comment: The other thing with `foreach` is that you can't change the list it is iterating over while it is running. (You can change the variable the list came from, but not the list value itself.) That's OK most of the time, but not always; sometimes you need `for` or `while`…

Comment: Thanks Jerry, Donal.  I think the bit about "you can't change the list it is iterating over while it is running" answers my follow-up question "is there a way to write my original code with only one `foreach` statement?"

Comment: For the cartesian product of three lists? Not really. Check out the [Tcler's wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Cartesian+product+of+a+list+of+lists) for ideas.

Comment: There is this form: `foreach alpha $list1 colour $list2 animal $list3 {puts "$alpha:$colour:$animal"}` but that's not a cartesian product, that is handling the *i*th element of each list per iteration. It's like what some other languages call `zip`